# jQuery + webforms: call an ashx, and refresh an image as a result

Tags: asp.net, jquery, webforms, file-upload, uploadify

Consider an ASP.NET page using the jQuery library [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com).

Here is the sequence of events on the ASP.NET webforms page:

1. User clicks on a file upload control. Plain old HTML `<input type="file" />`
2. User picks an image file from their system using a Browse dialog. All working fine.
3. A jQuery event fires. It calls an ashx that properly uploads as expected.
4. Now that the file is uploaded, **how can I change an `<asp:image>` on the calling .aspx page**? Would really like to do this without a postback!

Here's the code!

```
<asp:Image ID="imgChangeMe" runat="server" /><br />
<input type="file" name="uploadify" id="uploadify" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#uploadify").uploadify({
        'uploader'       : 'scripts/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'         : 'uploadify.ashx',
    'folder'         : 'uploads',
    'queueID'        : 'fileQueue',
    'auto'           : true,
    'multi'          : true
        });
       });
 </script>
```

Question:

How would you implement the changing of the `<asp:image>` to reflect the image that the user just uploaded?

This question really shouldn't be related to the uploading library, but rather, how to react to the return/end of execution of an .ashx? Should this be done in another jQuery method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely do this without making a postback. All you need is to get the path of the uploaded image. From `Uploadify` documentation I think you can get path from `fileObj` property or return it from server in `response property`:

**fileObj**: An object containing details about the file that was selected.

- **name** – The name of the file
- **filePath** – The path on the server to the uploaded file
- **size** – The size in bytes of the file
- **creationDate** – The date the file was created
- **modificationDate** – The last date the file was modified
- **type** – The file extension beginning with a ‘.’

**response**: The data sent back from the server.

Now if your aspx image is like:

```
<aspx:image id="myImage"...../>
```

you can set it as follows:

```
 //Uploadify hookup

 'onComplete': function(evt, qid, fObj, res){
     var f = fObj.filePath + fObj.name; //PUT SLASH IF REQUIRED BETWEEN
     $("img[id$='myImage']").attr("src",f);

     //for future readers who might be using master pages.
     $('#<%=myImage.ClientID %>').attr("src", f);
     $('#<%=txtMyImgPath.ClientID %>').val(f);
 }
```